# prevent multiple form submissions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

my app has multiple forms and I'm adding this everywhere

```
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

const onSubmit = (e) => {

    if (submitted) {
        return;
    }
    setSubmitted(true)
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('submitted!')
}

<form onSubmit={ (e) => onSubmit(e) }>...</form>
```

is there a more efficient way to do this for all forms? appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I usually disable the submit button while the form is submitting.  If it is successful, I render a success message or the next step or whatever makes sense instead of the form; if it's unsuccessful I pop up errors and enable the submit button.

Comment: Create a custom hook.

Comment: this is pretty much what Im doing here.. just disabling the form not the button thtat's fine... but a better approach could be possible? what's your idea @goto1

Comment: @handsome what do you see is inefficient in your example? Are you referring to performance efficiency or developer efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like what @goto1 mentioned in a comment, you may create a custom hook to use for a cleaner and reusable look. Here's my take on a custom hook called `useCbOnce` which calls any event callback once:

```
const useCbOnce = (cb) => {
    const [called, setCalled] = useState(false);

    // Below can be wrapped in useCallback whenever re-renders becomes a problem
    return (e) => {
        if (!called) {
            setCalled(true);
            cb(e);
        }
    }
}

const MyForm = (props) => {
    const handleSubmit = useCbOnce((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('submitted!')
    });
    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>...</form>;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this. thank you! but just found a small problem. when I submit the form I disable the re-submit. but let's say the backend reports an error like the form couldn't be submitted becase a field was missing. how to restore the previous state to allow the user to fix the data and submit again?

Comment: @handsome, no problem! Before answering your new question, it's a little out of scope of what's been originally asked because we didn't consider a backend. So it's probably best to create a new question. To answer it briefly, you can make a similar custom hook to accept a promise so that you can either resolve or reject a request via `fetch()`. From that, your custom hook can catch an error from the `fetch()` and simply call `setState(false)` to allow submissions again.

Comment: cool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686990/restore-form-submission-state-after-failed-submission-with-react-hooks

Comment: Year later I found this answer useful, I was using a separate component as a modal for getting user confirmation for some action, so form submission was happening twice on enter key, this one got my day saved! thanks @kmui2

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse `onSubmit` logic with simple [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook).

I oversimplified the logic so it won't cause unnecessary renders:

```
const useOnSubmit = () => {
  const [, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = useCallback(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(prevState => prevState || !prevState);
  }, []);

  return onSubmit;
};

// Usage
const onSubmit = useOnSubmit();
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>...</form>
```

Comment: Very elaborate solution!

Comment: where doest the actual logic for onSubmit lives?

Comment: Not sure I understand what does "logic lives" means

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that lets you customize what action happens on submit, but always prevents the default and only calls the action once.

```js
function useSubmitAction(action=null, dependencies = [action]) {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false)
  return React.useCallback(function (event, ...rest) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (submitted) return
    setSubmitted(true)
    if (action) action(event, ...rest)
  }, dependencies)
}

function FooForm(props) {
  const onSubmit = useSubmitAction((e) => console.log('submitting event type', e.type))
  return (<form onSubmit={ onSubmit }>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<FooForm />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Note that you may want to set the `submitted` state to true after you call the action, so that if errors occur then submit doesn't get set to true. But it depends on your use case.