# Restore form submission state after failed submission with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I want to restore the form state if form submission fails.
this is follow-up question on [prevent multiple form submissions in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657796/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-in-reactjs/60658054?noredirect=1#comment107350558_60658054)

```
const useCbOnce = (cb) => {
    const [called, setCalled] = useState(false);

    // Below can be wrapped in useCallback whenever re-renders becomes a problem
    return (e) => {
        if (!called) {
            setCalled(true);
            cb(e);
        }
    }
}

const MyForm = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    const handleSubmit = useCbOnce((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (name) {
            //all is good
        } else {
            console.log('please enter the name and submit again')
            // name is empty I need to restore the form state to allow the user to set and resubmit
        }
        console.log('submitted!')
    });
    return <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }><input onChange={ (e) => setName(e.target.value) } /></form>;
}
```

let´s say I submit a form without setting the name! I want to restore the previous form state so usr can fill the name and resubmit the form. basically calling *setCalled(false)* again but not sure where to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the custom hook to use the return value of the callback to decide whether the submit succeeded or failed. With that return value, the hook can stop allowing submissions after the first successful call.

```
const useCbOnceOrRetryOnFail = (cb) => {
    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);

    return (e) => {
        if (!succeeded) {
            setSucceeded(cb(e));
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
const handleSubmit = useCbOnceOrRetryOnFail((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!name) {
       console.log('please enter the name and submit again')
       return false; // Remember to set to false whenever fails
   }
   console.log('submitted!')
   return true;
});
```

---

With an asynchronous callback:

```
const useCbOnceOrRetryOnFail = cb => {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  return e => {
    if (!success) {
      setSuccess(true);
      cb(e, setSuccess);
    } else {
      e.preventDefault(); // Still need to preventDefault if clicked again
    }
  };
};

  const handleSubmit = useCbOnceOrRetryOnFail((e, setSuccess) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      console.log("please enter the name and submit again");
      setSuccess(false); // Remember to set to false whenever fails
    } else {
      console.log("submitted!");
       authenticate.then(() => {
         setSuccess(true);
       }).catch(() => {
         setSuccess(false);
       });
    }
  });
```

Note that we need to pass `setSuccess` callback instead of simply returning. This is because calling an api is asynchronous and we need the success state to be updated when it gets resolved/rejected.

Comment: hello @stackoverflow-newbie I was testing this approach but I encountered an issue when I set return false as the result of a failed api call. for example authenticate.then(console.log('all good').catch(error => return false); return true
how can I control this case? thanks so much for your help

Comment: Since api calls are a bit more involved, I'll update my answer to accommodate that.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can have `useCbOnce` return both a `once` function and a `reset` function:

```js
const useCbOnce = () => {
    const [called, setCalled] = useState(false);

    return {
      // Below can be wrapped in useCallback whenever re-renders becomes a problem
      once: (cb) => (e) => {
        if (!called) {
            setCalled(true);
            cb(e);
        }
      },
      reset: () => setCalled(false);
    }
}

const MyForm = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    const { cbOnce, reset } = useCbOnce();

    const handleSubmit = cbOnce((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (name) {
            console.log('submitted!')
            //all is good
        } else {
            console.log('please enter the name and submit again')
            reset();
        }
    });

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </form>
    );
}
```